# Declare and iterate through ArrayList of classes that extend a class

Tags: java, arraylist

I may be going about this the wrong way, but is it possible to iterate through a collection of classes that extend a specific class? i'm thinking of declaring like :

```
ArrayList<? extends InterfaceComponent> components = new ArrayList<? extends InterfaceComponent>();
```

but that throws an error. Is it possible?

Edit : And i would then iterate though it with :

```
    for (<? extends InterfaceComponent> t : components)
    {
        t.callSomeMethod();
    }
```

Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`ArrayList<InterfaceComponent> components = new ArrayList<InterfaceComponent>();`

And on that list You can have any object that implements `InterfaceComponent`.

EDIT: iterate like this:

`for (InterfaceComponent t : components) {
}`

Comment: I did not realise that if something extends it, then it can be added all the same. Guess i was going about it the wrong way, thanks

Comment: Where is my reputation? :3

Comment: I cant accept it for another like 9 minutes though, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The constructor operation *new* create a concrete instance compile-time defined class.

The instruction

```
new ArrayList<? extends InterfaceComponent>();
```

does'nt refer to any concrete class: instead, it define a set of allowed classes/interfaces (only the classes/interface what extends InterfaceComponent).

Theoric example

```
ArrayList<? extends JFrame> components1 = new ArrayList<HelpFrame>();//HelpFrame is a concrete subclass of JFrame - ok
ArrayList<? extends JFrame> components2 = new ArrayList<HelpDialog>();//HelpDialog is a concrete subclass of JFrame  -ok 

ArrayList<? extends JFrame> componentsBoh = new ArrayList<? extends JFrame>();//is componentsBoh a HelpFrame? Or a HelpDialog? I don't know! - ko
```

In left-side you can code  because you declare a collection of set of class, but at right-side you have to indicate in unambiguous way what kind of class you collect.

Comment: Makes more sense now, thanks for clearing that up for me, i never knew that

Comment: Fondamentally, it's the same concept you can instantiate a concrete class, but not an abtract class (it refers  more potential subclasses) or an interface (it refers  more potential classes or subinterfaces). The declaration works in a more abstract view.

Answer (score 1):

Take your `InterfaceComponent` and a few concrete classes:

```
public class A implements InterfaceComponent { }
public class B implements InterfaceComponent { }
public class C implements InterfaceComponent { }
```

When you declare:

```
List<? extends InterfaceComponent> list;
```

Then the list may only hold **one** concrete implementation of `InterfaceComponent`, once you create it as `list = new ArrayList<A>();`, it may only have `A` inside it.

However that is not what you want, as I see you want to store all subclasses of `InterfaceComponent` in your list, then you want:

List = new ArrayList<>();

Now you can store **any** concrete implementation of `InterfaceComponent`, so for example `A`, and/or `B` and/or `C`.